# Creating dynamic textbox not working in IE

Tags: html, dynamic

Creating dynamic textbox not working in IE

```
       // Create a new text input
        var newText = document.createElement('input');
        newText.type = "input";
```

It is working in all other browsers

Comment: I do not believe there is a type attribute value 'input' on tag 'input'. Could you supply more detail about the kind of data you expect to edit in the field?

Comment: Input elements cannot have the type attribute set to 'input', it's invalid. So, in this case - it's actually only IE that's really doing the right thing.. Just throw away the last line of your code sample above and it works fine - in IE9 at least. (don't have older versions to hand atm)

Comment: Hey you are right no need of second line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with help of setAttribute method.

Also please set the correct type like 'text' or 'submit', etc

```
        var newText = document.createElement('input');
        newText.setAttribute("type", "text");
```

Answer (score 1):

IE will not let you "change" the type of an input element. You will have to use a workaround like `document.createElement("<input type=\"text\" name=\"textBox\" >");`